# Error in visual studio about exit declaration

Tags: visual-studio-2008, opengl, opencv

**this error appears each time visual studio 2008 run my code which uses opencv and opengl :

- 1>c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio
  9.0\vc\include\stdlib.h(371) : error C2381: 'exit' : redefinition; __declspec(noreturn) differs
- 1>        c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio
  9.0\vc\include\gl\glut.h(146) : see    declaration of 'exit'
- 1>        c:\program files (x86)\microsoft    visual studio
  9.0\vc\include\gl\glut.h(146) : see declaration of    'exit'

how can I solve it?**

Comment: We're going to need more than just some error messages. What is the code that's having this problem, what libraries are you linking with, etc.

Comment: these are the library I included

Comment: #include <stdio.h>
#include <gl/glut.h>
#include <iostream>
#include "opencv2/core/core.hpp"
#include "opencv2/features2d/features2d.hpp"
#include "opencv2/highgui/highgui.hpp"
#include "opencv2/calib3d/calib3d.hpp"
#include "opencv2/imgproc/imgproc.hpp"
#include "math.h"
#include <stdlib.h>

Comment: I was told that it's a linker problem , do you have any idea how can I solve it? thanks in advance

Comment: You need to put those in your actual question, not in comments. Also, "do you have any idea how can I solve it?" No. You haven't said anything. All you've said is that you're getting some linker errors and you've included certain files. We need to see *code*.

Answer (score 3):

Try moving your #include "Glut.h" to the end of your list of includes.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and i can fix it with reorder include declaration. Making sure that your #include `<windows.h>` on top your list includes then #include `<stdlib.h>` and add #include `<GL/glut.h>` in your end list